# CollectionView doesn't display icons

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

First time I've created a UICollectionView..what am I missing? I've tried everything, the images are definitely in the app, correctly named and found in the array. Nevertheless they don't get displayed:

Header of my IconCell:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IconSelectionCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *iconImageView;

@end
```

Implementation my IconCell:

```
#import "IconSelectionCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation IconSelectionCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.restorationIdentifier = @"IconCell";
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;

        CGFloat borderWidth = 1.0f;
        UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        bgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        bgView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        self.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;

        CGRect myContentRect = CGRectInset(self.contentView.bounds, borderWidth, borderWidth);

        UIView *myContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myContentRect];
        myContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        myContentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
        myContentView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        [self.contentView addSubview:myContentView];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And my collectionViewController:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"IconCell";

    IconSelectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Do I need to add the imageview via code to the cell? I've just created an outlet in the Interface Builder…or what am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you registered your cell class in the controller's .m file? Have you checked to see whether the cell's initWithFrame method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to first try and get it working programmatically.  Give your `IconSelectionCell`class a property (not an IBOutlet) of a `UIImageView`.  Then in the `viewDidLoad` method of `IconSelectionCell`, set the following properties on the `UIImageView` property: `image`, `frame` (!), and `contentMode`

If you really want to use Interface Builder and storyboards, make sure the outlet is hooked up properly, and that the identity inspector for the prototype cell has your custom class name in its class field, and remember to set the image.  Its easier programmatically because you can lay out break points and see if code is actually being called and when it is being called.

Comment: Could you give an example of how this initialization would look programmatically? Thanks

Comment: In your interface:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView`

In your implementation's viewDidLoad:

`self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
self.imageView.frame = self.bounds;
self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Adjust the properties to change the aspect and position of the imageView